# Android Volley Signed Apk Issue

Tags: android, apk, android-volley, signed

I am working with an application where I am using volley plus with android studio. I am using volley plus gradle version 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+' gradle. When I make signed apk of my app my build process terminated with some warning and errors with runProguard true. There is any solution to solve this.

```
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack$HttpPatch: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.MultipartEntity: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.cache.SimpleImageLoader: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning:com.android.volley.cache.plus.SimpleImageLoader: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning:com.android.volley.misc.MultipartUtils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils
Warning:com.android.volley.misc.Utils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.misc.Utils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.android.volley.misc.Utils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.misc.Utils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.android.volley.misc.Utils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.misc.Utils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.android.volley.misc.Utils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack$HttpPatch: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack$HttpPatch: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack$HttpPatch
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack$HttpPatch: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateParseException
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateParseException
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.VolleyTickle: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.BasePart: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.BasePart: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.BasePart: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.BasePart: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.BasePart: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.Boundary: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.MultipartEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.MultipartEntity: can't find referenced method 'void setContentType(java.lang.String)' in program class com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.MultipartEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.toolbox.multipart.MultipartEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:com.android.volley.ui.PhotoView: can't find referenced method 'float sqrt(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
Warning:com.rey.material.drawable.ContactChipDrawable: can't find referenced method 'float ceil(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
Warning:com.rey.material.text.style.ContactChipSpan: can't find referenced method 'float ceil(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
Warning:there were 158 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning:there were 3 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
:app:proguardRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Answer (score 16):

Use this code in ProGuard:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**
```

Answer (score 5):

Since android API 23 Apache HTTP Client is removed from Android:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client
But Volley still uses it, that's why there is warn about can't find referenced class
We can ignore these warns, because Volley is still compiled using API 22:
https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/gradle.properties
Still should think about other better libray like OkHttp, which uses HttpURLConnection, if Volley doesn't update in the future.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation! Just ignoring the warnings did not assure me enough